# error to read number from input file

Tags: java, input

I'm making a program to count the number of connected component graph that I'll make using input.txt file. Inside the input.txt file, the texts are like below.

```
7 6 (enter)
0 1 (enter)
1 2 (enter)
2 0 (enter)
0 3 (enter)
3 2 (enter)
4 5 (enter)
```

And it works well, however when I change the first line data number 7 to 10 or bigger number, It shows error message like this,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Assignment41.main(Assignment41.java:28)
```

I don't know why this happens and how to debug this..
Any idea?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Assignment41 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        BufferedReader in;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));

            String graphGuide;
            graphGuide = in.readLine();

            int divider = graphGuide.indexOf(" "); 
            int NodeNum = Integer.parseInt(graphGuide.substring(0, divider)); 
            int EdgeNum = Integer.parseInt(graphGuide.substring(divider + 1));

            AdjList cc = new AdjList();
            for(int i = 0; i < NodeNum; i++){
                cc.insertVertex(i);
            }

            for(int j = 0; j < EdgeNum; j++){
                String temp;
                temp = in.readLine();

                int v1 = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, divider));
                int v2 = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(divider + 1));
                cc.insertEdge(v1, v2);
                cc.insertEdge(v2, v1);
            }

            for(int k = 0; k < NodeNum; k++){
                cc.BFS(k);
                System.out.printf(" ");
            }

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(cc.ccCount);

            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `trim()` your `String`s when parsing for an `Integer` if it has leading or trailing whitespace.

Otherwise, the `"0 "` string (notice the whitespace) won't be parsed and will throw `NumberFormatException`.

For instance:

`int v1 = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, divider).trim());`

Trimming the `String` will remove any leading or trailing whitespace, including line breaks et al.

See docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29).

You could also debug your code and make sure your sub-`String`s representing integer values are exactly parsed at the right index, but that might be a lot more work.

Finally, you also want to perform some basic checks before parsing, such as empty values after trimming.

As answered by [Rishal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5313817/rishal-dev-singh), use `String.split` to... split `String`s.

Comment: I fixed my code but still error occurs.. and this time the message is like 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at Assignment41.main(Assignment41.java:29)

What should I do ㅜㅜ

Comment: This means another of the `String`s you retrieved has come up empty after trimming. Likely your splitting methodology isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

`int divider = graphGuide.indexOf(" "); 
            int NodeNum = Integer.parseInt(graphGuide.substring(0, divider)); 
            int EdgeNum = Integer.parseInt(graphGuide.substring(divider + 1));`

You can very well use

```
String divider[] = graphGuide.split(" ");
            int NodeNum = Integer.parseInt(divider[0]); 
            int EdgeNum = Integer.parseInt(divider[1]);
```